# Find out every column sum by groupwise as row Using Pivot

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table tbTest like this:

```
q1 | q2 | q3 | type
--------------------
2  | 1  | 3  | student

3  | 2  | 1  | alumni

2  | 1  | 3  | alumni

1  | 1  | 3  | student
```

Now I want a new table which is based on the first table and finds the sum of every question by GroupWise convert it into like this:

q  | student | alumni
---------------------

q1 |  3     |    5

q2 |  2     |    3

q3 |  6     |    3

```sql
SELECT Student,
       Alumni
FROM
(SELECT q1, userType FROM tbTest2) tb1
PIVOT
(
    SUM(q1)
    FOR userType IN (Student, Alumni)
) AS tb2;
```

But using(above SQL) Pivot I can manage only one row like this:

```
student | alumni
---------------------

  3     |    5
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot the data and aggregate.  Based on the C# tag, I am assuming the database is SQL Server, in which case you can use `apply`:

```
select v.question,
       sum(case when t.type = 'student' then val else 0 end) as student,
       sum(case when t.type = 'alumni' then val else 0 end) as alumni
from t cross apply
     (values ('q1', t.q1), ('q2', t.q2), ('q3', t.q3)) v(question, val)
group by v.question;
```

In other database, you can do something similar using a lateral join or `union all`.

Comment: Brother thank you very very much, I spent my whole day but I didn't solve this problem. I just apply your solution and it worked very nicely. I'm grateful to you